# cfset problem with adding to existing variable

Tags: coldfusion, redefine

I am pulling my hair out working on what would seem to be easy problem.  But as a ColdFusion rookie I am just having a hell of a time figuring it out.

```
<cfoutput query="getSeasonAndRate">
    <cfset adultRate = groupRate>
</cfoutput>
```

So ... adultRate = 89

```
<cfset adultRate = 88>
```

So why does adultRate STILL equal 89?

Thanks! :D

Comment: You haven't provided enough information, post a larger code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query contains a column named "adultRate" then your CFSET statement is updating the query object, not the variables scope.

[This page](http://fusiongrokker.com/post/scope-priority-changes-in-coldfusion-9) (disclosure: on my own blog) discusses scope priority when reading and writing variables without explicitly specifying scope.

To fix your problem, change:

```
<cfset adultRate = groupRate>
```

to:

```
<cfset variables.adultRate = getSeasonAndRate.groupRate>
```

(assuming the groupRate value you want to get the value from is part of the query)

Comment: Not sure you're justified in voting Adam's answer down considering the fact that both answers say "answered 1 hour ago". He probably answered it at the same time you did, which just means he's as smart as you are, not that he took your answer :).

Comment: @Dan - I see "1 hour ago for" Adam and "2 hours ago" for this Stefano chap.

Comment: I feel that my answer added a significant amount of additional clarity (about scope priorities), making it worth posting my own answer. Sorry you didn't like it, @Stefano, but that's just the way the game is played.

Comment: Odd @Brian, I'm still seeing matching times for both. Would be nice if SO would show the exact time an answer was posted.

Comment: @Dan - It does, mouse over the "N hours ago".  @Stefano was at 17:55:03Z and @Adam was at 18:16:01Z.

Comment: The best written, most helpful answer should be selected as the accepted answer, even if it is written a year after another similar answer.

Answer (score 4):

It could be a scoping issue, try this:

```
<cfset variables.adultRate= 0>
<cfoutput query="getSeasonAndRate">
    <cfset variables.adultRate = getSeasonAndRate.groupRate>
</cfoutput>
<cfdump var="#variables.adultRate#">
```

It could also be that the query is returning more than one result, trying dumping out what is in that query like this:

```
<cfdump var="#getSeasonAndRate#">
```